# Remove OSX spotlight keyboard shortcut from command line

Tags: macos, bash, keyboard-shortcuts

how is it possible to disable the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> without using the System Preferences?

I've already found [this](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20131123074223584) but it hasn't been really helpful because I neither know the key nor how to set it to disabled.

Can somebody assist me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer does not work on a brand new install because the `Dict` entry at `AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64` does not exist until the user clicks on the UI.

In my case, I am trying to use `PlistBuddy` to write a macOS setup script. The requirement is no UI interactions.

I looked for solutions in the `PlistBuddy -help` output

```
Command Format:
    Help - Prints this information
    Exit - Exits the program, changes are not saved to the file
    Save - Saves the current changes to the file
    Revert - Reloads the last saved version of the file
    Clear [<Type>] - Clears out all existing entries, and creates root of Type
    Print [<Entry>] - Prints value of Entry.  Otherwise, prints file
    Set <Entry> <Value> - Sets the value at Entry to Value
    Add <Entry> <Type> [<Value>] - Adds Entry to the plist, with value Value
    Copy <EntrySrc> <EntryDst> - Copies the EntrySrc property to EntryDst
    Delete <Entry> - Deletes Entry from the plist
    Merge <file.plist> [<Entry>] - Adds the contents of file.plist to Entry
    Import <Entry> <file> - Creates or sets Entry the contents of file

Entry Format:
    Entries consist of property key names delimited by colons.  Array items
    are specified by a zero-based integer index.  Examples:
        :CFBundleShortVersionString
        :CFBundleDocumentTypes:2:CFBundleTypeExtensions

Types:
    string
    array
    dict
    bool
    real
    integer
    date
    data

Examples:
    Set :CFBundleIdentifier com.apple.plistbuddy
        Sets the CFBundleIdentifier property to com.apple.plistbuddy
    Add :CFBundleGetInfoString string "App version 1.0.1"
        Adds the CFBundleGetInfoString property to the plist
    Add :CFBundleDocumentTypes: dict
        Adds a new item of type dict to the CFBundleDocumentTypes array
    Add :CFBundleDocumentTypes:0 dict
        Adds the new item to the beginning of the array
    Delete :CFBundleDocumentTypes:0 dict
        Deletes the FIRST item in the array
    Delete :CFBundleDocumentTypes
        Deletes the ENTIRE CFBundleDocumentTypes array
```

This is my solution:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist -c \
  "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:enabled bool false"
```

If the key already exists, `PlistBuddy` will print out the following error:

```
Add: ":AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:enabled" Entry Already Exists
```

You have to delete the entry first:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist -c \
  "Delete :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64"
```

My full script disables both the `"Show Spotlight search"` and `"Show Finder search window"` options in **macOS Monterey**:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# target output for AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64
#
# <key>64</key>
# <dict>
#   <key>enabled</key>
#   <false/>
#   <key>value</key>
#   <dict>
#     <key>parameters</key>
#     <array>
#       <integer>65535</integer>
#       <integer>49</integer>
#       <integer>1048576</integer>
#     </array>
#     <key>type</key>
#     <string>standard</string>
#   </dict>
# </dict>

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist \
  -c "Delete :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:enabled bool false" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:value:parameters array" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:value:parameters: integer 65535" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:value:parameters: integer 49" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:value:parameters: integer 1048576" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:type string standard"

# target output for AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65
#
# <key>65</key>
# <dict>
#   <key>enabled</key>
#   <false/>
#   <key>value</key>
#   <dict>
#     <key>parameters</key>
#     <array>
#       <integer>65535</integer>
#       <integer>49</integer>
#       <integer>1572864</integer>
#     </array>
#     <key>type</key>
#     <string>standard</string>
#   </dict>
# </dict>

/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist \
  -c "Delete :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65:enabled bool false" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65:value:parameters array" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65:value:parameters: integer 65535" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65:value:parameters: integer 49" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65:value:parameters: integer 1572864" \
  -c "Add :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:65:type string standard"
```

*P.S. Changes require a full OS restart,  I haven't found a way around this yet.*

Comment: Can confirm on a brand new mbp 2021 silicon, that the above script works as described. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for providing an up to date answer :)

Answer (score 6):

The Spotlight keyboard shortcut is stored in `com.apple.symbolichotkeys`.

To disable it, run the following:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist -c \
  "Set AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:enabled false"
```

This takes effect after log out.

To re-enable, replace false with true.

Comment: This is not working on a fresh install of macOS Monterey. "Set: Entry, "AppleSymbolicHotKeys:64:enabled", Does Not Exist". If you click on the UI checkbox, the system creates the Dict and the error disappears. This said the accepted answer is not helpful on fresh installs.

Comment: To not confuse users coming to this answer I reassigned the accepted answer to something working on current Mac models.